VSCode App Bar Display Wrong Icon Left Activity Bar
VSCode Source Code icon doesn't display rigth.It should have display to me some paper icon but it show me Git icon.I know that it is not important much but it makes me lose some time to click wrong icon most of time.
enter image description here
I check the settings but i couldn't find antything helpfull.

From the image you posted it seems like the Explorer tab is hidden.  Point your cursor on the Left Activity Bar, right click and click on Explorer. There should be a "tick" next to Explorer.

It's the problem. The image I am showing you is from Explorer, but the icon and name are 'Source Control.
